# ¿Php o Javascript permites generar tonos por frecuencias como C en el que se le daba una frecuencia y una duración?

Tags: php, javascript

Recuerdo que C permitía crear un programa en el que secuencialmente se podían generar tonos por frecuencia y la duración de cada uno.
Ejemplo:
440hz 5000mls
220hz 2000mls
etc.

De manera que después se reproducía.

¿Esto lo puede hacer php o javascript?

Saludos.

Comment: Algo como esto? https://github.com/escottalexander/simpleTones.js

Comment: Hola. Ayer tuve una inquietud similar y luego de un par de horas de búsqueda llegué a **OscillatorNode** y luego de revisar y entender el tema, usando como clave de búsqueda dicha palabra, llegué a esta pregunta. (Cuando evidentemente ya no la necesitaba) ¿Podrías agregarle una etiqueta o dos indicando generación de sonido?

Answer (score 1):

con php podes generar un wave o mp3 y luego reproducirlo mediante [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)

pero si es un tono algo mas simple es con javascript usando [OscillatorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode)

```js
// create web audio api context
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// create Oscillator node
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, audioCtx.currentTime); // value in hertz
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
oscillator.start();
```

Comment: una implementación práctica ( y adictiva para los fanáticos del tb-303 ) de osciladores en javascript: http://errozero.co.uk/acid-machine/ ( dev console, beautify instruments.js )